# PHP insert into mysql database with dates

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to be able to add children into a database, which are connected to their parents (who has a member id MID). I believe that the error lies within the date format (atleast that's what I believe), I have also tried to use strtotime($dob), however this didn't change anything.

```
   $name = htmlspecialchars($_GET['Name']);
   $dob = $_GET['DOB'];
   $newDOB = date("Y-m-d", $dob);
   $mid = $_GET['mid'];

   if(isset($_GET['Name'], $_GET['DOB'], $_GET['mid']))
       $alert = true;
   if(!empty($name) && !empty($newDOB) && !empty($mid))
       add_family_member($mid, $newDOB, $name);
```

The function that adds the member:

```
function add_family_member($mid, $dob, $name)
{
    global $con;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Children(MID, DOB, Name) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    if($stmt)
    {
        $b = $stmt->bind_param("iss", $mid, $dob, $name);
        if($b)
        {
            $e = $stmt->execute();
            if($e)
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: try to remove if($b){} or echo $b

Comment: You can't mix PDO and MySQLi. Btw `DateTime` is specially made for... date and times ;-)

Comment: are you getting any insert at all or error ? if error, post it

Comment: Where am I mixing PDO with MySQLi?

Answer (score 1):

```
function add_family_member($mid, $dob, $name)
{
    global $con;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Children(MID, DOB, Name) VALUES(:mid, :dob, :name)";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    if($stmt)
    {
        return $stmt->execute(array(
             'mid' => $mid,
             'dob' => $dob,
             'name' => $name
        ));           
    }

    return false;
}
```

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php for more examples

Comment: Doesn't work, wouldn't this only work with using PDO?

Comment: you dont said what you use, but yes this is pdo.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
function add_family_member($mid, $dob, $name)
    {
        global $con;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Children(MID, DOB, Name) VALUES(:mid, :dob, :name)";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':mid', $mid);
        $stmt->bindParam(':dob', $dob);
        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```